# vue js data unable to loop

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

i am making shopping cart system with laravel session and vue js. my part of vue js code is as follows.first i looped the product and then using click event , i sent product to endpoint, actually in cart/session.
my part of vue js code is as below.

```
<div v-for="product in products">
      <div class="card" >
        <div class="card-header">{{product. name}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card-body">
                    <img :src="product.image">
                    <p>{{product.price}}</p>
                    <p>{{product.category_id}}</p>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addProductToCart(product)">Add to cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
```

```
export default {

    data:function(){
        return {
            lists:[]// everything is pushed in lists array
        }


methods:{
        addProductToCart(product){
           // alert(product)
            axios.get('/cart',{
                 params: {
                    product: product
                }
            }).then((response) => {
        });

mounted:{
  axios.get('/list')
            .then(function (resp) {
                console.log(resp)
                app.lists=resp.data
            })}
```

Now my controller are

```
public function StoreInCart(Request $request) {
        //dd($request->get('product'));
         $request->session()->push('product',$request->product);
         return session('product');

    }
    public function listProduct(Request $request){
        $product = $request->session()->get('product');
        return $product;
    }
```

in vue too i see data stored in following format

```
lists:Array[7]
0:"{"id":1,"name":"Keyshawn McDermott Sr.","description":"Error aut quia id dolorem est aut doloribus nesciunt. Quod nihil tenetur ea id voluptas molestias id. Debitis amet dolor est fugiat sed autem.","category_id":1,"price":59,"image":"http://loremflickr.com/400/300?random=36","created_at":"2019-07-16 10:12:27","updated_at":"2019-07-16 10:12:27"}"
1:"{"id":2,"name":"Marlene Reichert","description":"Debitis asperiores sed sit assumenda unde quo natus. Consequatur est labore tenetur quae. Eius distinctio ea omnis aspernatur porro earum quae.","category_id":3,"price":76,"image":"http://loremflickr.com/400/300?random=71","created_at":"2019-07-16 10:12:27","updated_at":"2019-07-16 10:12:27"}"
2:"{"id":1,"name":"Keyshawn McDermott Sr.","description":"Error aut quia id dolorem est aut doloribus nesciunt. Quod nihil tenetur ea id voluptas molestias id. Debitis amet dolor est fugiat sed autem.","category_id":1,"price":59,"image":"http://loremflickr.com/400/300?random=36","created_at":"2019-07-16 10:12:27","updated_at":"2019-07-16 10:12:27"}"
3:"{"id":1,"name":"Keyshawn McDermott Sr.","description":"Error aut quia id dolorem est aut doloribus nesciunt. Quod nihil tenetur ea id voluptas molestias id. Debitis amet dolor est fugiat sed autem.","category_id":1,"price":59,"image":"http://loremflickr.com/400/300?random=36","created_at":"2019-07-16 10:12:27","updated_at":"2019-07-16 10:12:27"}"
4:"{"id":2,"name":"Marlene Reichert","description":"Debitis asperiores sed sit assumenda unde quo natus. Consequatur est labore tenetur quae. Eius distinctio ea omnis aspernatur porro earum quae.","category_id":3,"price":76,"image":"http://loremflickr.com/400/300?random=71","created_at":"2019-07-16 10:12:27","updated_at":"2019-07-16 10:12:27"}"
5:"{"id":18,"name":"Heidi Kuhlman","description":"Eveniet et dolorum aut magnam ut amet reprehenderit eveniet. Nihil incidunt voluptas aut amet et.","category_id":7,"price":274,"image":"http://loremflickr.com/400/300?random=2","created_at":"2019-07-16 10:12:27","updated_at":"2019-07-16 10:12:27"}"
```

Because of above format , i can't loop the data

```
<div class="card-body" v-for="list in lists">
   {{list.name}}// i got nothing
</div>
```

on looping lists i got nothing.
Please help me. How to loop data stored in Lists Array.

Comment: Try returning a JSON `return $product->toJson();`.

Comment: i got error in browser "Call to a member function toJson() on array"

Comment: Can you test `$request->session()->push('product',json_decode($request->product));` ?

Comment: Thanks @SamirMammadhasanov, you solved it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. You can select my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save product details as json object.(in your case it's json strting, not json objects).

Change your push function of controller like below:

`$request->session()->push('product',json_decode($request->product));`

Complete code:

```
public function StoreInCart(Request $request) {
    //dd($request->get('product'));

     #changes done on next line
     $request->session()->push('product',json_decode($request->product));

     return session('product');

}
public function listProduct(Request $request){
    $product = $request->session()->get('product');
    return $product;
}
```

Comment: and you dont forget use to :key in v-for 

<div v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
  <!-- content -->
</div>

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Samir Mammadhasanov might be a better option, but if you want to loop the Array like you mentioned, you could simply parse it like this:

```
    <div class="card-body" v-for="list in lists">
       {{JSON.parse(list).name}}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to JSON.parse() the items in the list. As others have mentioned, these are JSON strings and not parsed objects yet.

You might want to consider creating a sub-component for each list item and then creating a computed property that returns the parse object like this:

```
parsedObject() {
    return JSON.parse(this.jsonString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question but after seeing your blade code I recommend you to use a key attribute with Vue js List Rendering.

```
<div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
      <div class="card" >
        <div class="card-header">{{product. name}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card-body">
                    <img :src="product.image">
                    <p>{{product.price}}</p>
                    <p>{{product.category_id}}</p>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addProductToCart(product)">Add to cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
```

**OR**

```
 <div v-for="(product,index) in products" :key="index">
          <div class="card" >
            <div class="card-header">{{product. name}}</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                        <img :src="product.image">
                        <p>{{product.price}}</p>
                        <p>{{product.category_id}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addProductToCart(product)">Add to cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
```

**From Vue Docs:**

When iterating over an object, the order is based on the enumeration order of Object.keys(), which is not guaranteed to be consistent across JavaScript engine implementations.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html